# SQL Server returns different result for the same Date selection query, In different scenarios

Tags: sql-server

I was trying to get a date based on Timezone and I was nearly successful with that. But I got an issue when I incorporate that query with the stored procedure.
Here is the code which gives me the correct output.

```
    DECLARE 
@TimeZone VARCHAR(100) = 'India Standard Time'
declare @EndDate DATETIME = (SELECT (CONVERT( datetime,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()  AT TIME ZONE @TimeZone)))   
select @EndDate
```

and the output is (correct o/p)

```
2019-12-23 20:43:18.020
```

Then I incorporate it with a stored procedure

which comes under an `if` condition

O/P is like this

```
Dec 23 2019  8:38PM
```

can anybody help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the variable looks correct but just shown in different format. You can force it to show in the format you want:

```
select CONVERT(nvarchar(100),@EndDate,120) as EndDate;
```